# What does electron actually do in quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, orbitals

I know that electrons are considered waves in quantum mechanics and it has a probability density region of where it could be found. But what does it actually do? Does it stay at one part or move to another? Does it get affected by the charge of nucleus which influences its path? Does it even move around and be found at a different place at a different time?

Comment: Are you familiar with quantum mechanics? maybe my answers  here will help  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/194590/the-observer-experiment-quantum-mechanics/195709#195709  another https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/630001/is-the-probabilistic-behaviour-of-quantum-mechanics-something-new-not-directl/630016#630016 another https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6738/simple-explanation-of-quantum-mechanics/6765#6765

Comment: I will take a look into it , thanks ! @annav

Comment: I'm in the mood of jokes. So here's "analogical" question,- When you don't look at your girlfriend in her flat,- What does she do ? Sitting at couch ? Doing yoga ? Or maybe running across rooms as a madman ? Probably she does everything at once, assuming emotional nature of woman ;-) So does the electron.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In quantum mechanics, an electron is not regarded as a particle nor a wave. However, it is something that displays *both* particle and wave-like characteristics. An electron is completely described by its [quantum state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_state), a rather abstract vector. Just like vectors you may be familiar with, we can represent the quantum state in a number of different bases. For example, the quantum state in the position basis is called the position-space [wave function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_function) (a complex scalar field). The norm-squared of this wave function is the probability density you mentioned in your question! However you might want to represent the quantum state in another basis, the most common being the momentum and energy bases, and you may find the corresponding wave functions and probability densities for those *observables* as well.

Once you understand what the quantum state of an electron is, your question about its evolution has a very straightforward answer: the evolution of the quantum state is determined by the [Schrödinger equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation). The Schrödinger equation is a second-order partial linear differential equation. The exact form of the equation depends on the particular system you are handling. So yes, the presence of a nucleus, or charges, or barriers change the form of the Schrödinger equation and affect the evolution of the quantum state. As the quantum state evolves, so too will its representation: the wave function evolves. In this particular picture, we don't think of the electron as moving from point to point. We think of its wave function (or its norm-squared: the probability density for some observable) diffusing over time in a manner unique to the system at hand.

The notable exception to this evolution comes when we measure the electron. The measurement of any observable (position, momentum, energy, etc.) causes the wave function to [collapse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_function_collapse): a phenomenon which deserves its own thread.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to describe an electron by assuming that quantum theory accurately describes what is happening in reality: this is commonly called the many worlds interpretation of quantum theory. For reasons that are unclear, this is controversial despite the fact that quantum theory makes very accurate predictions.

Quantum theory describes an electron's location in terms of quantum observables that are represented by Hermitian operators. The eigenvalues of those Hermitian operators represent the possible outcomes of a measurement. The equations of motion of quantum theory describe how observables evolve over time. Those equations don't describe a single particle at a single point. Nor do they describe a single value of the observable evolving over time. Rather they describe a process of many versions of each electron with different observable values interfering with one another. This interference happens evn when there is only a single particle in the experiment and is called single particle interference. For a popular account of single particle interference see Chapter 2 of "The Fabric of Reality" by David Deutsch.

To get predictions from quantum theory you have to use a relative state that describes what observables were measured in the past and what their values were. There is a formula called the Born rule that combines the state and an observable to provide the expectation value of the observable:
$$\sum_i p_i a_i$$
where $a_i$ is the $i$th value of the observable and $p_i$ is the probability of that value.

The same explanation involving multiple versions is true for every other kind of particle in your body: electrons, protons, neutrons etc. If there are multiple versions of every particle in your body, then there are multiple versions of you. And the same is true for all the objects around you. When a system is undergoing interference with its other versions and it interacts with another system and makes a record in that other system the interference is suppressed: this effect is called decoherence. Objects like you and the objects you can see with the naked eye evolve a lot slower than the time required for decoherence so the versions of large objects tend to be sorted into layers each of which acts approximately like the universe as described by classical physics:

https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.2189

https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0104033

Roughly, the observables describe all of the versions of these systems evolving and the state tells you what version you last saw.

This approximation is not perfect and there are experiments, such as entanglement experiments, where the only known explanation is the existence of multiple versions of decoherent objects carrying quantum information:

https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9906007

https://arxiv.org/abs/1109.6223

Other interpretations of quantum theory fall into two categories. (1) Theories that fudge the issue of what is happening in reality, such as the Copenhagen and statistical interpretations. (2) Theories that modify quantum theory to eliminate the many versions of each system. Theories in category (1) make unclear experimental predictions because being able to test whether an experiment works requires explaining what is happening in reality during the experiment so you can explain what counts as the experiment working correctly or incorrectly. Theories in category (2) have lots of problems such as not reproducing many of the predictions of relativistic quantum mechanical theories:

https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.00568

There are a couple of questions to ask whenever anybody talks about those other interpretations. (1) What does your theory say is happening in reality during interference experiments? (2) What does your theory say is happening in reality during entanglement experiments? If they can't answer then their theory is worse than quantum theory.

Answer (score -6):

Assuming the electron is mathematically described as a *dimensionless-point* particle the amplitude probability wavefunction describes all possible instantaneous locations the electron can be found around and **inside** the nucleus of an atom.

Because one picture equals 1000 words here is an educational cartoon toy pedagogical model illustration of a hydrogen  ${ }^1 \mathrm{H}$ atom with the nucleus at the center (red dot) and its one electron shell (blue) around it:

[image: H-1 Electron shell]

${ }^1 \mathrm{H}$ Atom Electron shell toy model cartoon *(animation credits: horntorus.com)*

The blue shell above represents the amplitude probability wave function of the electron of all possible positions it can take simultaneously in superposition. As you can see the electron can be found also inside the nucleus of an atom. That may look impossible physically but remember that QM is an [effective theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_theory) and model describing accurately quantitative results of experiments and never claims that this is also the actual physical reality.

*There is no microscope that can show you optically what an electron charge is actually doing around the nucleus of an atom.*

However, what actually the probability wavefunction here refers to, is a dynamic electromagnetic flux manifold *(i.e. EM flux is real, alike to the magnetic flux of a permanent magnet)* that engulfs and pierces the nucleus of the atom as a spherical torus shaped standing EM wave which is the best analogy for what we describe as a wave-particle.

About the confusing statement also heard many times in popular science media that the electron is in superpositon and and can be found at any position of the wavefunction at the same time simultaneously! This *process description* is an effective explanation and has nothing to do with actual physical reality although the end result *(i.e. wavefunction of electron inside the atom)* is correct. Why such a confusing explantion? Well, see for your self in the illustration above. How else would you describe the blue shell wavefunction using a point (i.e. electron)? Unavoidably, you have to use the superposition in space and time thus all possible positions at once.

Conclusively, most of the frustration people have of the apparently nonphysical explanations of QM is sourcing from the fact that this explanations are taken by these people literally to be actual physical. As soon one understands that these explanations are effective explanations and mathematical interpretations of a model and not the actual physical that however accurately predicts the  results of quantum interactions, the problem and so called weirdness of QM is resolved.

Comment: You provide an animated picture, but don't provide an adequate explanation what it represents or where it comes from. Not even a reference. Your also call the wave function for the electron a "dynamic electromagnetic flux manifold." Are you saying that the electron is an EM field? That would not be correct.

Comment: @flippiefanus Just a toy illustration model for pedagogical purpose. Also, according to QFT, fields is all there is in nature. The electron quantum field physically consist exclusively by EM flux and the electron charge is a distortion of this field.

Comment: It seems that you believe that the EM field is the only field there is. The electron is also a field that is (according to our current understanding) distinct from the EM field. The same is true for all other fundamental particles.

Comment: You are right, electron field, photon field, quark field etc. There is no discrete EM field in QFT and I never mentioned the term "EM quantum field" for QFT only the term EM flux. However, the OP is asking for a physical and even ontological explanation. So, what you suggest consists physically every point in these fields? Water?

Comment: We can only say what we know. That, unfortunately, may not be an ontological answer. Anything more than that is just speculative guesswork.